# Quickblox tap message with picture [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am implemented QuickBlox chat module with attachments. I want to take it a step ahead by adding a tap gesture. Whenever an attachment is send; I want to add a tapGesture to it so that it can open up in a full screen image view for better viewing.

Any help will be appreciated.